# Why overflow equals carryin xor carryout in Riscv?

Tags: riscv

Just like the title, why overflow equals carryin xor carryout in Riscv? In ALU, we say we can caculate the overflow bit using xor carryin and carryout, however, I cannot find the reason of this.